# matlab ind2rgb trobule (showing and saving is different)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to save the figure as a png file (or any)
But I want to save only the image and the image does not have to have high resolution. 
Just screencapture-like quality is fine for me.  (image-checking purpose)

Following is my example in matlab:

```
figure, imagesc(),axis image;
D=get(gca,'Children'); Child=get(D); data=Child.CData;
m8=uint8((data-min(min(data)))./max(max((data-min(min(data))))).*255); % uint 255 normalization
imshow(m8),axis image; 
rgbImage = ind2rgb(m8, jet);
imwrite(rgbImage,'test.png');
```

Here, if I remove "imshow(m8),axis image", the saved image is awkward. 
I don't know why the result is different whether there is imshow(m8) or not.

anyone could help me?

I am using Matlab R2014a in windows 7 64bit

---

+
sometimes, it works properly when imshow(m8) is removed. 
But once it does not work improperly,

```
 imshow(m8)
```

determines the result. I cannot understand this.

Comment: Look into [export_fig tool](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) if it helps.

Comment: What do you mean by awkward? Please be specific. If you mean pixelated (i.e. low resolution) then you should consider upsampling it first using `interp2`, you'll also find `meshgrid` helpful for that task

Comment: @Dan I tried to upload image but my reputation is not enough.
http://s21.postimg.org/ryd9nfhhv/test.png
http://s21.postimg.org/b9btrikwj/test2.png
something like saturation

Comment: @Divakar I tried but this is a slower process about two fold

Comment: I thought the key for this trouble is `ind2rgb`. While I tried various versions, I found the solution. `figure, imagesc(),axis image; D=get(gca,'Children'); Child=get(D); data=Child.CData; m8=uint8((data-min(min(data)))./max(max((data-min(min(data))))).*255); imwrite(m8,jet,'test.png');` I found that  `imwrite` itself can transform index to rgb colormap. So I don't need to use ind2rgb and there is no more trouble. But still I don't know why my trouble happened.

Comment: nope. sorry.
this time, images are mostly black. but if i execute `imshow`, `imwrite(m8,jet,'test.png')` work properly.